# Subscribe issue with RACSignal

Tags: ios, objective-c, mvvm, racsignal

I am using the `MVVM` paradigm in my iOS with `RACSignal` as well. So far things have worked out great. However I am experiencing a problem when subscribing to signals. On the first subscription things work fine. However further subscriptions don't.

**The code**

In my `viewModel` I have an `RACSignal` declared like this:

viewModel.h

```
@property (strong, readonly, nonatomic) RACSignal *updatedContentSignal;
```

viewModel.m

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) RACSubject *updatedContentSignal;
```

It is then initialised like so in the viewModel's `designated initialiser`:

```
self.updatedContentSignal = [[RACSubject alloc]init];
```

Then when I actually use the signal in the `viewModel` I do this sort of thing: 
Where needed in various places in the viewModel - typically within a web service block method

```
[(RACSubject *)self.updatedContentSignal sendNext:nil];
[(RACSubject *)self.updatedContentSignal sendCompleted];
[(RACSubject *)self.updatedContentSignal sendError:error];
```

In the `viewController` I subscribe to signal like so:

```
[self.viewModel.updatedContentSignal subscribeNext:^(id x) {

    } error:^(NSError *error) {


    } completed:^{


    }];
```

I subscribe once to the signal on `viewDidLoad`

So all works on the first `viewDidLoad` call

**The problem**

When I navigate away from the `viewController` and come back to it `viewWillAppear` is called, and the `viewModel`fires off various methods that trigger the signal:

```
  [(RACSubject *)self.updatedContentSignal sendNext:nil];
    [(RACSubject *)self.updatedContentSignal sendCompleted];
    [(RACSubject *)self.updatedContentSignal sendError:error];
```

However the `viewController` no longer receives the signal. It seems it only works not he first subscription.

Is there a way to have it that the signal will continue to work each time one of the `updateContent` signal is call/ fired?

Comment: As your code is not very comprehensive I can only say a signal will be dismissed as soon as it is completed (either via sendCompleted or sendError:). So if you want to continue you'll have to only use sendNext:. Only use sendCompleted, in case you want to show, that this is no longer used. SendError is used, in case you receive an error.. so in your web service block you'd need something like if(!error) sendNext: else sendError:error;

Comment: Thanks for the informative post. You are correct that its sending complete that effectively kills the signal until the next time I recreate it when I show a new viewController with it. If you could put your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks @Dimitri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code is not very comprehensive I can only say a signal will be dismissed as soon as it is completed (either via `sendCompleted:` or `sendError:`).

So if you want to continue you'll have to only use `sendNext:`.
Only use `sendCompleted`, in case you want to show, that this is no longer used.

`SendError:` is used, in case you receive an error. so in your web service block you'd need something like:

```
if(!error) {
    sendNext:xxx; 
} else {
    sendError:error;
}
```